# Building QT with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I know there have been a few questions before regarding this, but not too much up to date.

I am developing a project with Visual Studio 2015 express edition and I wish to add a GUI to my project via QT.

The latest version of QT (5.8.0) has a VS 2015 version, so I assume it is compiled using Visual Studio instead of MinGw.

Sorry if this is a very noob question. I have no experience with QT, but how do I then integrate my QT project into my VS project, do I build the GUI code first in QT?

If I will create a GUI using the .ui file in QT and then generate the source code for this, can I just copy the source code to my VS Project. I assume I have to configure the project file in VS as how will VS know where to find the dlls and header files for QT? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need the VS Tools for Qt. They work with >= Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

You can get them [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/index.html) and all information about how to use them.

> Qt VS Tools integrate the Qt development tools into Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, and later. This enables developers to use the standard Windows development environment without having to worry about Qt-related build steps or tools.

The main features of Qt VS Tools are:

- Wizards for creating new Qt projects and classes.
- Automated build setup for the Meta-Object Compiler (moc), User Interface Compiler (uic), and Resource Compiler (rcc).
- Import and export of Qt project files (.pro) and project include files (.pri).
  *Automated conversion of a Qt VS Tools project to a qmake project, or the other way around.
- Integrated Qt resource management.
- Integrated Qt documentation.
- Debugging extensions for Qt data types.

Comment: It should be good to mention in answer how author of question should deal with currently available VS project files. http://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-managing-projects.html here available description, but there is no direct answer for the question. Also it's not obvious if Qt VS Tools works with Express Edition of Visual Studio 2015, or it's needed to setup at least Community Edition.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Max that's true. After spending a long time trying to understand why VSIXInstaller was failing , I discovered Express Edition does not allow any extensions. I have now installed VS community edition 2013 which is another free version and qt-vs tools seems to work fine.